# OpenSSL API d2i_x509_bio returns null

Tags: xcode, macos, openssl

My application is using OpenSSL version 1.0.1h. I am trying to upgrade to latest version.

As the first step I have built OpenSSL

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc
make
```

Then I copy the .a and header files to respective places. I am not changing my base code. It works fine with OpenSSL version 1.0.1h. d2i_x509_bio returns null from 1.0.1i onwards. I am passing the same parameters while using both versions. Any idea why this is happening and what is the fix for this.

NS: I have ensured that my app uses the newly built libraries and headers and not the ones from OS X SDK

Comment: Did you try to check the error code with [ERR_get_error](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ERR_get_error.html)?

Comment: Yes .. This is what I got - encoding routines:c2i_ASN1_OBJECT:invalid object encoding d2i_X509_bio

Comment: @SeemaKadavan did u get any solution for above problem